# Cannot import opencv after succesfull install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, 64-bit, raspberry-pi4

I try to install opencv on my Raspberry Pi with 4GB RAM (Raspberry OS version Linux 5.15.84-v8+ aarch64). Instructions I found on [q-engineering](https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.5-on-raspberry-64-os.html). After a 2hr lasting build process the make announced that opencv was succesfully installed. When I try to import it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

But opencv appears to be succesfully installed. When I run `opencv_version` I got:

```
$ opencv_version
4.7.0-dev
```

and:

```
/usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation
/usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation
/usr/local/bin/opencv_version
/usr/local/bin/opencv_model_diagnostics
/usr/local/bin/opencv_waldboost_detector
/usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration
/usr/local/share/licenses/opencv4
/usr/local/share/opencv4
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4
/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc
/usr/local/include/opencv4
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/gapi/opencv_includes.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp
```

Looking for `cv2` or `*cv2*` yielded nothing except what was already listed above. The date/time of the files conform to the time I ran the install script.

Next I tried opencv-lite according to instructions [from the same source](https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-lite-on-raspberry-pi.html). Same result: succesful installation, traces of newly put opencv files but `import cv2` still fails.

To complicate matters I use `anaconda` environments. I got two: `base` and `rpi`. I installed with `rpi` activated. In both no trace of `opencv` or `cv2` and in both cases import fails. Some information where the system fetches `python`:

```
$ which python
/home/arnold/bin/anaconda/envs/rpi/bin/python
(rpi) arnold@bottie:~/bin/opencv/opencv/build
```

There is python in /bin/python and /usr/bin/python I found out with vscode. I tried both and both failed.

My questions:

- did installation of opencv *really* succeed?
- if so, is it possible to 'connect' the installation to a running version of python, preferably a conda environment?
- if not, what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: I had a similar problem & it was down to OpenCV not being installed globally but installed into a profile.

Comment: So I should disable any environment and install it again? I can give that a try tonoght :-)

Answer (score 0):

I try this links. [install OpenCV 4 for RPI 4](https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/) It worked for me using RPi 4B/8GB 64-bit.

- Do update first
- Install OpenCV
- Check `getBuildInformation()`
- After that if not getting . Then install sudo apt
  pyhton3-opencv-contrib

No needed to do `cmake`. And you ready to go.

Comment: It took me 5 minutes